# Some problem in drawing undirected graph with loops(TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

I'm trying to draw some undirected graphs with loops using TikZ, but running into some problem.

My set up is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
 \node (0) at (0,0) {(0,0)};
 \node (1) at (3,0) {(0,1)};
 \node (2) at (0,-4) {(1,0)};
 \node (3) at (3,-4) {(1,1)};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=black,thick}]
\path [-] (0) edge (1);
\path [-] (0) edge (2);
\path [-] (1) edge (3);
\path [-] (1) edge (2);
\path [-] (0) edge (3);
\path [-] (2) edge (3);
\path [-] (0) edge[loop] (0);
\path [-] (1) edge[loop] (1);
\path [-] (2) edge[loop] (2);
\path [-] (3) edge[loop] (3);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph $I_1 \times I_1$} \label{$I_1 \times I_1$}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces [image]

The problem here is that I want the loop at the bottom to somehow move that it doesn't intersect with any other edges. How would one do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `edge[loop below]`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Hi, I had tried before of you comment but the problem is `\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}` where every loop are little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many attemps I have deleted `%\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}` and I have fixed the loop for every loop edge using the parameters `loop,in=60,out=120,looseness=10`. These are chosen after many compilations for me using Papeeria (a TeX engine editor to compile in `LaTeX`). I hope that the loop are good. If they are not very good you can change the values of `loop,in=...,out=...,looseness=...`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
 \node (0) at (0,0) {(0,0)};
 \node (1) at (3,0) {(0,1)};
 \node (2) at (0,-4) {(1,0)};
 \node (3) at (3,-4) {(1,1)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=black,thick}]
\path [-] (0) edge (1);
\path [-] (0) edge (2);
\path [-] (1) edge (3);
\path [-] (1) edge (2);
\path [-] (0) edge (3);
\path [-] (2) edge (3);
\path [-] (0) edge[loop,in=60,out=120,looseness=10] (0);
\path [-] (1) edge[loop,in=60,out=120,looseness=10] (1);
\path [-] (2) edge[loop,in=-60,out=240,looseness=10] (2);
\path [-] (3) edge[loop,in=-60,out=240,looseness=10] (3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{Graph $I_1 \times I_1$} \label{I_1 \times I_1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This is my original code with little loops:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every loop/.style={}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
 \node (0) at (0,0) {(0,0)};
 \node (1) at (3,0) {(0,1)};
 \node (2) at (0,-4) {(1,0)};
 \node (3) at (3,-4) {(1,1)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw=black,thick}]
\path [-] (0) edge (1);
\path [-] (0) edge (2);
\path [-] (1) edge (3);
\path [-] (1) edge (2);
\path [-] (0) edge (3);
\path [-] (2) edge (3);
\path [-] (0) edge[loop above] (0);
\path [-] (1) edge[loop above] (1);
\path [-] (2) edge[loop below] (2);
\path [-] (3) edge[loop below] (3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{Graph $I_1 \times I_1$} \label{I_1 \times I_1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @Phil I'm glady to help you...at this moment I not remember how I can delete your mistake of the caption. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Sebastiano The problem is not the caption but the label.  Try instead `\label{I_1 times I_1}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ok and thank you very very much.

Comment: @henrimenke it is true. The label not want $ symbols.

Comment: @Sebastiano Wrong, the `$` are actually fine.  It's `\times` that trips up the label.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you so much for that information I didn't know. Unconsciously I always use letters and numbers for labels.+1